# Move multiple elements on canvas and also clear the rect

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem where i have 2 object for example and i did some moving stuff using the keyboard events. Now the problem is that i don't know when to clear the canvas so i can keep multiple instances of them and also to move them individually.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-game');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Set Canvas To Whole Screen
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

// Player
class Player {
  constructor(xPosition = 0, yPosition = 0, height = 25, width = 25) {
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
    this.yPosition = yPosition;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.moveEvents = this.moveEvents.bind(this);
  }

  draw() {

    // this.clear();

    let { xPosition, yPosition, height, width} = this;

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(xPosition, yPosition, height, width);
    context.closePath();    
    context.fill();

    // Bind Events
    this.initEvents();
  }

  initEvents() {
    canvas.addEventListener('keydown', this.moveEvents);
  }

  clear() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
  }

  moveEvents(event) {
    let keyPressed = event.keyCode;

    if (keyPressed === 38 || keyPressed === 87) {
        this.yPosition -= 5;
    } else if (keyPressed === 40 || keyPressed === 83)  {
        this.yPosition += 5;
    } else if (keyPressed === 37 || keyPressed === 65)  {
        this.xPosition -= 5;
    }  else if (keyPressed === 39 || keyPressed === 68)  {
        this.xPosition += 5;
    }

    this.draw();
  }

}

// Enemy
class Enemy extends Player {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

function update(...components) {
  components.forEach((item) => {    
    item.draw();
  });
}

function init() {
  let player = new Player(100, 100);
  let player2 = new Player(200, 200);

  update(player, player2);
}


init();
```

It works as it is but it leaves the trail while updating. Many thanks.

Demo Here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54mcfx8n/2/)

Comment: why is `this.clear()` commented out in the `draw` function?

Comment: @HaykoKoryun i have no ideea where to put the this.clear() so both shapes move and don't leave a trail.

Comment: It looks like it's in the right place....

Comment: it's not working like i wanted it to work, i just want to see the black rectangles not the black line that's being drawn

Answer (score 0):

1. move the `clear` function out of the `Player` class (and into the same context as `update`) since it shouldn't be responsible for clearing the global `canvas`
2. call `clear` in the `update` function before the draw calls of the players e.g.

   ```
   function update(...components) {
     clear();
     components.forEach((item) => {
       item.draw();
     });
   }
   ```
3. replace the `draw` call from the `moveEvents` function with the global `update` function as you want to redraw the whole scene again after each move (as you need to clear the whole canvas)

Comment: sorry, just realised that you don't call the update method apart from when initialising the code, let me update the description to take that into account...

Comment: whatever i do one of them dissappears  and never appears again.